# Cosmos DB documents result in an array

Tags: json, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Suppose I am querying Cosmos DB with the following query `(SELECT c.Name, c.Job FROM C`) an having the following 2 documents as a result:

```
[{
"Name":"test",
"Job" : "Hello"
},
{
"Name":"test2",
"Job" : "Hello2"
}]
```

I would like to have the results in a array for every attribute like following:

```
[{
"Name" : ["test", "test2"],
"Job" : ["Hello", "Hello2"]
}]
```

I would like to know if this is possible in cosmos db and if anyone has experience with this. I would appreciate it!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to get your expected output with one SQL in Cosmos DB. You need to make two call:

```
SELECT 
    value c.Name
FROM c
```

AND

```
SELECT 
    value c.Job
FROM c
```